# ionic v4 back button canGoBack alternative

Tags: android, angular, ionic-framework, back-button

I have an ionic application that is currently based on version 4. In version 4 they switched to angular routing model and basically parts of the `NavController` were deprecated and I'm looking for the proper replacement for `NavController.canGoBack`.

To give some context I basically have an app that requires a pin code unlock prior to showing application contents, on my pin-code page I already implemented a guard to prevent deactivation (basically prevent). However, while implementing the back button I noticed that when I press the back button on the very first page. It seems to bypass the guard, and instead the screen turns blanc and then shows the pin code page again.

I have my suspicions that when I issue an `this.navCtrl.back();` on it refreshes the page and it doesn't actually use the javascript based routing. So to that end I was hoping I would be able `NavController.canGoBack` to give me some indication if there's anything to navigate back to.

Comment: If the answers below didn't serve you, mention me and i'll post the alternative for it..

Answer (score 0):

To detect if there's anything to navigate back to you will have to implement a service that saves the history of previous routes in an array.

One implementation of such a service can be found [here](https://blog.hackages.io/our-solution-to-get-a-previous-route-with-angular-5-601c16621cf0).

Answer (score 0):

The simplest would be importing

```
import {Location} from '@angular/common';
```

and then

```
 constructor( private _location: Location,) { }

    this._location.back() // this would route back if back is possible
```